# "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification" in android studio

Tags: android

This is my gradle file--------

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification"

[image]

I got "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification" ërror in  android studio....
how to resolve this...

Comment: Simply change your build tool version higher or equal than your appcompat dependency. Or change the app compat  dependency to 25.0.0.

Comment: let me share an article I wrote on about managing dependencies versions effectively http://www.technotalkative.com/androiddev-tip-4-managing-android-dependencies-versions/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
etc 
put same version to all support library and +. It will work

Comment: there is again a warning: "Avoid using + in version numbers" :)

Comment: It is working right. Even I was worried about warning but till now I haven't got any error yet. Still if you want , then other answers are correct probably no other solution I know of. :)

Answer (score 0):

Reason to getting this error is your **buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"** and your appcompat dependency is **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'**.

In this case your buildToolsVersion is lower than your compile dependency so try to increase your buildToolsVersion or you can set your appcompat dependency to 25.0.0.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use same version code for all design support library like bellow:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```